# how to make airflow dag wait VM to finishes its job before doing the next task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

High level description of my workflow

What my vm does -- get data from gcs, process data, save the processed data to gcs

What my dag currently does -- start the vm >> stop the vm >> do the rest of data transformation job.

When I run the above dag, it starts the vm and stops the vm right after that. I would want to make my dag to wait for the vm to finish its job.

Note: kubernates/cloud run is not an option for me.

Comment: did you correctly define your tasks' relationships ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/tasks.html#relationships

Comment: Do you need to run a command in your VM to get data from GCS, process it and save the process data to GCS ?

Comment: Instead of manually control on your side the start/stop operation on a VM, do you think about a `Dataflow` job ?

Comment: @DevYns yes, other computational method is not an option for me at the moment.

Comment: @MazlumTosun I will have a look at that too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the output file name which your VM will write to GCS, you can add a sensor between `start_vm` and `stop_vm`, which check if the output file is created or not every X seconds, once it's created, the sensor is marked as `succeeded` and the task `stop_vm` is started:

```py
gcs_output_sensor = GCSObjectExistenceSensor(
    bucket="bucket_name",
    object="path/to/file"
)
start_the_vm >> gcs_output_sensor >> stop_the_vm >> do_the_rest_of_data_transformation_job
```

If not, you can instead of running the script which process the data automatically when the VM is up, you can run the VM and use the `SSHOperator` to run the script, in this case the task will wait the script, and the other task will wait it.